# Zend 1.12 Flash Message always coming up

Tags: php, zend-framework, server

In my site, I upgraded my PHP version and flash messages got display over the site. 
  As I checked in my view.phtml file that if Flash Message contains data it should show. It is showing the Flash messages all the times.Like

```
Item has been updated successfully.
```

I looked over internet but couldn't able to find the issue. Did anyone face the same issue? 
I am using following things in my class ,

Under init function:

`$this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');`

Under my specific action:

`$this->_flashMessenger->addMessage(array('message' => 'Item updated successfully.',
                'status' => 'alert-success'));`

In my view.phtml file-

`<div><?php echo $this->flashMessages(); ?></div>`

All was working fine from last year, This happened just after upgrade of PHP version.

Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade from/to which PHP version? Assuming that your logic flow is sound (i.e., you are not actually calling `addMessage()` on every page), I would look at the view-helper itself. Since there is no `flashMessages()` view-helper in the standard [ZF 1.12 View component](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html), this must be a custom view-helper in your app. Perhaps something there is detecting messages incorrectly? When you say that "I checked in my view.phtml file that if Flash Message contains data it should show", how are you checking that? Just some ideas...

Comment: David Weinraub I got the issue, It was caching enabled on the updated server. ACL cache which was not clearing the flash messages arrays. Thanks for your comment. Have a great day !!

Comment: glad you solved your problem. As a matter of SO housekeeping, may I suggest that you either add your solution as an Answer (yes, you can answer your own Questions on SO) or delete the original Question? Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the issue, This issue was to due to ACL cache enabled on the server. After disabling it, Everything works as expected.

Thanks !!